# AWS Elastic BeanStalk- Settings get reset after some time

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my PHP application on Elastic Bean Stalk. The application takes at least 1 and at most 5 audio files (each size can go upto 2GB). It first uploads the files to S3 and then to auphonic.com via API call. The volume of the instance was 8GB originally, I changed it to 15GB. I have changed the nginx.conf file settings to the following parameters:

```
client_max_body_size 7500M;
proxy_connect_timeout 3600s;
proxy_send_timeout 3600s;
proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 3600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3600s;
```

The application is working fine. However, twice a month I have noticed that the above settings get reset along with the volume to 8GB.
I have to make increase the volume again and change the nginx.conf file and restart nginx server to keep the application working.

Why settings are being reverted? Kindly assist.

Answer (score 1):

The first place to look would be `Configurations > Managed Updates` in the online portal (or `aws:elasticbeanstalk:managedactions` section via the output of `eb config` when using the [eb cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-config.html))

If Managed Updates are enabled, and Instance Replacement is enabled, then it's likely that your instance is being replaced based on the Managed Updates schedule and it does so with the default machine settings.

If you want custom options to persist from one instance to the next, [you'll want to define and manage them with an .ebextensions folder and config files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). These are tracked and committed files which instruct EB on a wide variety of commands and configurations related to an application instance.